Can parties in an MPC protocol establish a shared secret with an external party?
Creating a shared secret(ECDH) with a single private key is easy:
a·B = b·A
Does the same apply to MPC? and if so how?
Based on Gennaro and Goldfeder CCS 2018

If three party,  it is easy, if more than one party, ask as a bug in github?

@kelalaka Assuming Alice has a share locally and another share in a remote server, if she wants to establish a shared secret with Bob, how can she do it?

Finally solved it. You need to perform computation on each secret share xi then add solution:
func main() {
    modQ := common.ModInt(tss.EC().Params().N)
    for key := range keys {
        result := tweakMul(keys[key].Xi, key, keys[key].Ks, data)

        if key == 0 {
            sum = result
            continue
        }

        sum = modQ.Add(sum, result)

    }

    fmt.Println("Sum of results:", sum)
 }

func tweakMul(xi *big.Int, i int, ks []*big.Int, tweak []byte) *big.Int {
    modQ := common.ModInt(tss.EC().Params().N)
    wi := xi
    for j := 0; j < len(ks); j++ {
        if j == i {
            continue
        }
        ksj := ks[j]
        ksi := ks[i]
        if ksj.Cmp(ksi) == 0 {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("index of two parties are equal"))
        }

        // big.Int Div is calculated as: a/b = a * modInv(b,q)
        coef := modQ.Mul(ks[j], modQ.ModInverse(new(big.Int).Sub(ksj, ksi)))
        wi = modQ.Mul(wi, coef)
    }

    tweakBif := new(big.Int).SetBytes(tweak)

    miulti := modQ.Mul(wi, tweakBif)

    return miulti
}


